# ImageReader format overridden in some devices

Tags: android, android-camera2

I have an `ImageReader` that is used to get the preview frame's data (byte array). It is configured with the recommended image format of `YUV_420_888` like so:

```
mPreviewImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width,
            height, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 2);
```

When the listener I set in `mPreviewImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener();` is called, I retrieve an image:

```
Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
```

In some phones, I see in the log the following printout with a `ImageReader_JNI` tag:

> ImageReader_imageSetup: Overriding buffer format YUV_420_888 to
>   32315659.

I searched and it appears that the format is overridden to `YV12`. I tried looking at the c++ code of ImageReader and discovered where this happens:

```
int bufFmt = buffer->format;
if (imgReaderFmt == HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCbCr_420_888) {
    bufFmt = buffer->flexFormat;
}
if (imgReaderFmt != bufFmt) {
    if (imgReaderFmt == HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCbCr_420_888 && (bufFmt ==
            HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP || bufFmt == HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YV12)) {
        // Special casing for when producer switches to a format compatible with flexible YUV
        // (HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCbCr_420_888).
        ctx->setBufferFormat(bufFmt);
        ALOGD("%s: Overriding buffer format YUV_420_888 to %x.", __FUNCTION__, bufFmt);
}
// ... rest of the code
```

So it seems that the buffer's format is `YV12` while the `ImageReader`'s format is `YUV_420_888` as I set it.

That brings me to 2 questions regarding this situation that correspond with the 2 options that I have (as far as I can see):

1. Why is the buffer's format `YV12`, where is it set and can I change this?
2. I can add `YV12` support - but I need to know that this override occurred. But when calling `image.getFormat()` I receive 35 which means `YUV_420_888`. Is there a way to know if this override took place?

Any other ideas are welcome.

Comment: On my devices this only happens in devices that have LEGACY hardware level and that support the YV12 format. If that format is available, I just select it as the ImageReader format, otherwise I stay with YUV_420_888. Do you also get a gralloc warning with YV12?

Comment: Did you found a solution you can share ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It's weird that this issue isn't more popular with all of the AR and image recognition apps. Looks like many are still using the original Camera API.